# calculate total minutes between two timestamps across multiple records using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql 9.1 table with 2 timestamps that record time periods that may overlap. Example:

```
ID   Start                     End
1    2014-01-19 21:14:59+00    2014-01-19 21:30:00+00
1    2014-01-19 21:16:29+00    2014-01-19 21:31:30+00
2    2014-01-19 21:19:29+00    2014-01-19 21:40:30+00
2    2014-01-19 21:29:59+00    2014-01-19 21:45:00+00
```

I need to get the sum of all minutes per ID across these rows ensuring that time is not double counted, so that the output would be:

```
ID   Hour      Total Minutes
1    21        n
2    21        n
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please show an example of your desired output.

Comment: Is this too hard to do with sql / postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only two rows per group, you can do the calculation using brute force.  Add up all the time in the two periods.  Then subtract the overlap if any:

```
select id,
       (sum(extract(epoch from end - start)) -
        (case when max(start) < min(end)
              then extract(epoch from max(start) - min(end))
              else 0
         end)
        ) / 60
from timeperiods tp
group by id;
```

The solution is harder if you have multiple rows.  If that is your problem, then post another question.

Comment: Hi Gordon. There are many rows per ID and many IDs. How should I reword the question when the question subject states 'across multiple records'?

Comment: @Steve . . . provide sample data and say something like "begin and end" timestamps.  I interpreted the "two timestamps" as two rows.